# Unexpected results when using std::stringstream

Tags: c++, debugging, stringstream

I am a beginner in C++, started last week. I am trying to make a simple program converting a number of inches to foot inch notation: E.g. 62 turns into 5'2". However when I try to compile I have some error in line 8. I don't know what it is. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
string ConvertToFootInchMeasure (int totalInches){
    string feet = ""+totalInches/12;
    string inches = "" + totalInches%12;
    stringstream converted;
    conveted<<feet;
    converted<<"'";
    converted<<inches;
    converted<<"\"";
    return converted.str();
}
```

Comment: `string feet = ""+totalInches/12;` and `string inches = "" + totalInches%12;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

That code can be easily fixed like this:

```
string ConvertToFootInchMeasure (int totalInches){
    stringstream converted;
    // Do inline calculations and use formatted text output for the results
    converted << (totalInches/12) << "'" << (totalInches%12) << "\"";
    return converted.str();
}
```

To explain further: You tried to concatenate the numeric results of the `totalInches/12` and `totalInches%12` operations to a `std::string` variable, but the right side of the statement doesn't do that.

**Note:**

[`std::string operator+(std::string, char c)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) doesn't do conversion of numerics to string and concatenation as you tried to use with:

```
string feet = ""+totalInches/12;
```

also it seems to be even worse in your case because the term

```
""+totalInches/12
```

does pointer arithmetics for a `const char*` pointer, and the `string` variable is initialized from e.g. a pointer address `"" + (62/12)`.